# Using the plus sign for multiple tags - Does StackOverflow allow double escape sequences?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-search

When browsing questions by tag on StackOverflow we can use the plus sign to include multiple tags.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+asp.net

Have they turned off the double escape blocking on the filtering module or is there a safer way to allow this kind of functionality?

Comment: Funny, this is the third time in less than 24 hours that this particular IIS setting has popped into my life without ever bumping into it before.